# Bresenham line coding not drawing a line

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

I tried to use the following code [Bresenham line drawing](https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2017/01/bresenhams-line-drawing-algorithm-c-c.html) but by OpenGL GLUT project.
I have successfully run the code but no outcome result.
I'm trying to draw to points between the two points p1(5,8) and P2(9,11).
But seems have a problem with my for loop.

```
int x1,x2,y1,y2;
void drawline(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
 {
int dx, dy, p;
int x,y;
dx=x1-x0;
dy=y1-y0;
//x=x0;
y=y0;
p=2*dy-dx;
for(x=x0; x<=x1; x++)
{
    if(p>=0)
    {

        y=y+1;
        p=p+2*dy-2*dx;
         glBegin(GL_POINTS);
         glVertex2i(x,y);
         glPointSize(45);
         glEnd();
    }
    else
    {

        p=p+2*dy;
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
         glVertex2i(x,y);
          glPointSize(45);
          glEnd();
       y=y0;
    }
}

  void myDisplay()
  {
  drawline(x1, x2, y1, y2);
  glFlush();
  }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

printf("Enter the value of x1 : ");
scanf("%f",&x1);
printf("Enter the value of y1 : ");
scanf("%f",&y1);
printf("Enter the value of x2 : ");
scanf("%f",&x2);
printf("Enter the value of y2 : ");
scanf("%f",&y2);

glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize (500, 500);
glutInitWindowPosition (100,100);
glutCreateWindow ("bresenham Line Algo");
// myInit();
glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Personally, I would be very suspicious about a website that offers a C++ solution with `#include <iostream.h>` in it. There seems to be a whole chunk missing from your algorithm (checking/changing initial values for dx, dy, y0 and x0). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) for a better description and pseudocode.

Comment: Thanks but could you help me find my own solution. what is the problem

Comment: Run the code in the debugger and watch the variables. Alternatively, insert some `printf()`. -- Please decide, which language you use. C and C++ are quite different.

Comment: One generally expects a drawline call to draw both endpoints.

Comment: `while(x<x1)` causes the loop not to execute if `x1` is less than `x0`. If that is not the problem, edit the question to provide a [mre], including sample values for which the code does not work and clear descriptions of the observed behavior and of the desired behavior. If the code does work for certain values, also give an example of such a set of values, along with a description of the observed behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have modified the code. I want to draw the points  between the two points(5,8) and (9,11). What causes the problem please?

Comment: The program in the question will not compile because there is a closing `}` missing, likely in `drawline`. It will not execute properly because the `scanf` calls use `%f`, which is for converting input to a `float`, but they are passed the addresses of `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, and `y2`, which are `int`. So this program will not set the values of those variables correctly, so it will not draw a line correctly. Please read the information about an [mre]. Remove the graphics calls from your program and insert `printf` calls to print the values of the things it computes so you can trace execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had double global variables which I didn't notice. Thank you all for your support.